# «Несмотря на все обстоятельства». Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

Правильно ли обособлять оборот? Если нет, то почему? Если да, то почему?

Comment: А как Вы сами предполагаете?

Answer (score 1):

[**НЕСМОТРЯ НА (что)**, *предлог*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_482)

Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «несмотря на», **обычно обособляются** (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу).
*Это оказался тощий, **несмотря на постоянное воровство,** огненно-рыжий кот-беспризорник с белыми подпалинами на животе* (К. Паустовский. Кот-ворюга).

Евгений Миронов: *«Это история художника, который, **несмотря на все обстоятельства,** до последнего хотел жить, работать и, не считая себя великим творцом, оставить после себя нечто, что хоть как-то оправдывало бы его невероятно тяжелую жизнь».* [о Ван Гоге]

***Несмотря на все эти обстоятельства,*** он преодолел свои многочисленные физические проблемы и преуспел как студент и музыкант (о Патрике Генри Хьюзе).

Предлог «несмотря на» в составе обстоятельственного оборота не выделяется запятой лишь тогда, когда он тесно связан со сказуемым. В этом случае при удалении дополнения предложение теряет смысл. Чаще всего это встречается в простом нераспространённом предложении, когда предлог идет сразу за сказуемым.
*Будем жить несмотря на трудности.*
*Они стремятся быть вместе несмотря на все обстоятельства.*